# Looking for Ayah and Hadith on Mercy/Morality

Tags: quran, hadith, reference-request, morality, ethics

For my studies, I am looking ayah or hadith which unambiguously mentions or strongly suggests that conscience/morality/altruism/mercy are God-given values. The one I have is:

> Narrated Abu Huraira: I heard Allah's Messenger saying, Verily Allah
>   created Mercy. The day He created it, He made it into one hundred
>   parts. He withheld with Him ninety-nine parts, and sent its one part
>   to all His creatures. Had the non-believer known of all the Mercy
>   which is in the Hands of Allah, he would not lose hope of entering
>   Paradise, and had the believer known of all the punishment which is
>   present with Allah, he would not consider himself safe from the
>   Hell-Fire. ---*[Sahih al-Bukhari 6469, Book 81, Hadith 58](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/58)*

From which we learn not only that such values are God-given but also *created* by God. Are there any other? Especially useful would be if I could find ayah/hadith where it is mentioned that such values are actually Signs of Allah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rather general statement, saying that everything comes from Allah (especially guidance), can be found in several verses of the Qur'an like:

> And whatever you have of favor - it is from Allah . ... ([16:53](https://legacy.quran.com/16/53))

**Mercy**

Let's start with mercy, first a quote from the qur'an:

> ... "but My mercy encompasses all things" ... ([7:156](https://legacy.quran.com/7/156))

So it is Allah's mercy that encompasses all His creation.

But maybe the hadith you've quoted which can be found in more or less similar wordings in many other hadith compilations such as Musnad Ahmad, Mustadark al-Hakim, [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1344340), [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/172), Sahih al-Bukhari ([1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/31), [2](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/81/58)) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/50/25) (see also [1](https://sunnah.com/muslim/50/21), [2](https://sunnah.com/muslim/50/23), [3](https://sunnah.com/muslim/50/25)):

> Verily, Allah created, on the same very day when He created the heavens and the earth, one hundred parts of mercy. Every part of mercy is coextensive with the space between the heavens. and the earth and He out of this mercy endowed one part to the earth and it is because of this that the mother shows affection to her child and even the beasts and birds show kindness to one another and when there would be the Day of Resurrection, Allah would make full (use of Mercy).

is more expressive and comes directly to the point.

Maybe one could also say this hadith shows that Allah gives or takes the Mercy:

> A bedouin came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and said, "You (people) kiss the boys! We don't kiss them." The Prophet said, "I cannot put mercy in your heart after Allah has taken it away from it." ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/29), see [here](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/85) the version of Sahih Muslim)

**Morality:**

As for morality or good behaviour you may find a disconnected hadith in the book of ibn abi Dunya called Makarim al-Akhlaq مكارم الأخلاق:

> إِنَّ هَذِهِ  الأَخْلاقَ مَنَائِحُ يَمْنَحُهَا اللَّهُ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ مَنْ يَشَاءُ مِنْ عِبَادِهِ ، فَإِذَا أَرَادَ اللَّهُ بِعَبْدٍ خَيْرًا مَنَحَهُ مِنْهَا خُلُقًا صَالِحًا  (Source:   [مكارم الأخلاق](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?indexstartno=0&hflag=1&pid=127101&bk_no=223&startno=13))
>    <sub>My own translation take it carefully</sub>
>   These manners are gifts from Allah exalted and glorified be He, he gives whoever He wants among his slaves, so if Allah wanted good with a slave He would give him a good manner.

al-Mundhiri and al-Haythami considered the above narration as weak. In this book you may find many other similar statements, but most are based on ahadith that can be rejected, for example these two similar narrations which are (marfo'):

- > لِلَّهِ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ مِائَةٌ وَسَبْعَةَ عَشَرَ خُلُقًا ، مَنْ جَاءَ بِخُلُقٍ مِنْهَا أَدْخَلَهُ اللَّهُ الْجَنَّةَ  ([Source](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?indexstartno=0&hflag=1&pid=127101&bk_no=223&startno=3))
- > " خِصَالُ الْخَيْرِ ثَلاثُمِائَةٍ وَسِتُّونَ خَصْلَةً ، إِذَا أَرَادَ اللَّهُ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ بِعَبْدٍ خَيْرًا جَعَلَ فِيهِ خَصْلَةً مِنْهَا يُدْخِلُهُ بِهَا الْجَنَّةَ " ، قَالَ أَبُو بَكْرٍ : أَفِيَّ مِنْهَا شَيْءٌ ؟ قَالَ : " نَعَمْ ، جَمْعَاءُ مِنْ كُلِّ شَيْءٍ ! " ([Source](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?indexstartno=0&hflag=1&pid=127101&bk_no=223&startno=10))

Both state that Allah has seventeen good manners or morality attributes and while the first states if anybody has one of them would enter paradise the second states that if Allah wants good for His slave he would give him one of them and let him enter paradise by this manner or attribute.

There's also the commonly known Hadith -which actually has no backup-:

> “My Lord taught me good manners and He taught me well” (See Fatwa islamqa #[21635](https://islamqa.info/en/21635))

Note that one could count some du'a's as evidences for this as we ask Allah to give us good manners and refuge from bad manners (see for example in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/240) and in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/222)).

This hadith might be used as an evidence that Allah gives good manners or attributes:

> Some property or something was brought to Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and he distributed it. He gave to some men and ignored the others. Later he got the news of his being admonished by those whom he had ignored. So he glorified and praised Allah and said, "Amma ba'du. By Allah, I may give to a man and ignore another, although the one whom I ignore is more beloved to me than the one whom I give. But I give to some people as I feel that they have no patience and no contentment in their hearts and I leave those who are patient and self-content **with the goodness and wealth which Allah has put into their hearts** and 'Amr bin Taghlib is one of them." 'Amr added, By Allah! Those words of Allah's Apostle are more beloved to me than the best red camels. ([Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/47))

Finally the Qur'an offers some proofs that Allah has given us the guidance for moralities:

> O children of Adam, We have bestowed upon you clothing to conceal your private parts and as adornment. ... ([7:26](https://legacy.quran.com/7/26))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of these ayath. They are helpful in many ways, but not particularly in the way I am looking for. The example I have given explicitly mentions that mercy is something Allah created and explicitly mentions that it is put in our hearts and it is the very reason we show mercy to others. I already use your examples in sections where I mention **how Merciful Allah is**.

Comment: I accepted because I think the hadith about the bedouin and ayah 7:26 are relevant.

Comment: @blackened I recommend you not to accept an answer if you don't find it  helpful And nobody is ordering you to accept an answer so you have time to wait and see whether others might be able to answer in a better manner or could provide better evidences!